# Adding Security Layer to OData Service

Tags: iphone, wcf, web-services, ipad, odata

Im creating an Odata service that is being exposed to an IPhone application and potentially other receivers. Im just wondering what is the best method for adding security to the Odata service so all data requests to the Odata provider are authenticated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great series of posts about auth over OData services here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/tags/authentication/